# Shiny Programming: Reactive output as input of functions

Tags: r, function, shiny, rstudio, renderer

I am beginner in R programming as part of my assignment i  am try to make a tool which predict delay in report generation  Here i am able to manage the linear reg on the the input using below function  however i need to use the estimates which from `Summary(summary(runRegression())$coefficients)` to calculate the  time delay of report.
 any possible way for it?

for example the output of summary is below i need to make function  using this.
something like  `Y = IN + X1(apps1) + X2(Apps2) + ..`

```
Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  29.05882   11.50971  2.524723 0.02013993
Apps1      -29.05882   24.14297 -1.203615 0.24279200
```

Code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$histdata<- renderDataTable(ccdata)
output$Msg <- renderText("Impacted applications are")
output$outmsg <- renderText("Print the control output")
output$values<- renderDataTable(total())
output$Apps <- renderText(input$Apps)
output$prdmsg<-renderText("Predicted delay from agree deiliver time")
runRegression <- reactive({
lm(as.formula(paste(input$controlInput," ~     ",     paste(input$Apps,collapse="+"))),data=ccdata)
})
output$prdvalue <- renderPrint({
if(!is.null(input$Apps)){
summary(runRegression())$coefficients
} else {
print((Warning="Please select impacted Source."))
}
})
```

Comment: Not following clearly what you need. But, assuming you have a vector of `apps` and a vector of `coefficients`, you can write `y = coefficients[1] + apps * coefficients[2:length(coefficients)]` and use that result. Or, you can use the `predict` function. It will require you organize `apps` into a data frame like `ccdata`.

Comment: thanks  a lot i manage it like below hope it will  be fine,output$prdvalue <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$Apps)){
     cals <- subset(summary(runRegression())$coefficients, select=Estimate)
     colSums(cals) 
    } else {
      print((Warning="Please select impacted Source."))